# Python classes type error 'no attribute __getitem___

Tags: python, class, types

I wrote the following class:

```
class Average(object):

def __init__(self,invoer):
    self.regel = invoer
    self.persons = []

def parse_input(self):        
    lengte = self.regel.split('\t')[2]
    gewicht = self.regel.split('\t')[3]
    self.lengte = float(lengte)
    self.gewicht = float(gewicht)
    return self.lengte, self.gewicht

def add_person(self):
    self.persons += [self.lengte, self.gewicht]

def get_average_bmi(self):
    total_bmi = 0
    for i in self.persons:
        total_bmi += i[0]/i[1]
    average_bmi = total_bmi/len(self.persons)
    self.average = average_bmi
    return self.average
```

And the program looks as follows:

```
from BodyMassIndex import Average 
from ipy_lib import file_input

bestand = file_input().splitlines()

for i in bestand:
    bmi = Average(i)
    bmi.parse_input()
    bmi.add_person()
average_bmi = bmi.get_average_bmi()
```

The input, that comes in the bestand variable looks like this:

```
Barbara Lerner  V   1.54    67  No
Danny Coronado  M   1.84    89  No
Diana Knox  V   1.69    58  Yes
Penney Rose V   1.56    102 No
Jessica Richman V   1.58    63  Yes
```

The parse_input() method takes the length en heigth of each person, add_person adds it to a list and get_average_bmi should calculate the bmi of every list within that list and calculate the average of that.

However, i get this error: 
    total_bmi += i[0]/i[1]
    TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

What is going wrong in this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to fix `add_person()`:

```
def add_person(self):
    self.persons.append([self.lengte, self.gewicht])
```